# How to set Load Generator on Red Hat server (Linux)

Tags: testing, load, load-testing, loadrunner

I am trying to set load generator on Linux machine while the Controller will be on windows machine.

how can I do that and what are the steps to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install:

```
cd /media/Linux // the directory which contains the installer.sh
./installer.sh
```

Start/Stop LG:

```
cd /opt/HP/HP_LoadGenerator/bin
./m_daemon_setup -install
./m_daemon_setup -kill
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!